# What is simple way to convert dynamically Kotlin/Js objects to plain javascript object?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

For example, we have this structure:

```
data class Item(
        val city: String,
        val name: String
)

val structure = mapOf("items" to listOf(
                Item("NY", "Bill"),
                Item("Test", "Test2"))

)
```

And I want to get this object in Javascript:

```
var structure = {
  "items": [
    {
      "city": "NY",
      "name": "Bill"
    },
    {
      "city": "Test",
      "name": "Test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

How we could convert `map` from Kotlin to `dynamic` type with such structure in Javascript?

I find only this explicit way:

```
fun Map<String, Any>.toJs(): dynamic {
    val result: dynamic = object {}

    for ((key, value) in this) {
        when (value) {
            is String -> result[key] = value
            is List<*> -> result[key] = (value as List<Any>).toJs()
            else -> throw RuntimeException("value has invalid type")
        }
    }

    return result
}

fun List<Any>.toJs(): dynamic {
    val result: dynamic = js("[]")

    for (value in this) {
        when (value) {
            is String -> result.push(value)
            is Item -> result.push(value.toJs())
            else -> throw RuntimeException("value has invalid type")
        }
    }

    return result
}

fun Item.toJs(): dynamic {
    val result: dynamic = object {}

    result["city"] = this.city
    result["name"] = this.name

    return result
}
```

I know that is possible to do this also with **serialization/deserialization**, but I think it will be slower and with some overhead.

Does anybody know simple way to covert Kotlin `object` to plain Javascript `object` (`dynamic` Kotlin type)?

Comment: maybe .asDynamic() ?

Comment: `.asDynamic` only reinterprets this value as a value of the `dynamic type`

Comment: @kurt did you find anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using this simple function

```kotlin
inline fun <I> objectOf(
    jsonObject: I = js("new Object()").unsafeCast<I>(),
    writer: I.() -> Unit
): I {
    writer(jsonObject)
    return jsonObject
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
interface Structure {
    var items: Array<Item>

    interface Item {
        var city: String
        var name: String
    }
}


fun main() {
        val structure0 = objectOf<dynamic> {
            items = arrayOf<dynamic>(
                objectOf {
                    city = "NY"
                    name = "Bill"
                    orAnything = "Literly, anything!"
                },
                objectOf { city = "Test"; name = "Test2" }
            )
        }
        println(JSON.stringify(structure0))
        // {"items":[{"city":"NY","name":"Bill","orAnything":"Literly, anything!"},{"city":"Test","name":"Test2"}]}
    
        val structure1 = objectOf<Structure> {
            items = arrayOf(
                objectOf {
                    city = "NY"
                    name = "Bill"
    //                orAnything = "Literly anything" // Compile time Error: Unresolved reference: orAnything
                },
                objectOf {
                    city = "Test"
                    name = "Test2"
                }
            )
        }
    
        println(JSON.stringify(structure1))
        // {"items":[{"city":"NY","name":"Bill"},{"city":"Test","name":"Test2"}]}
    
        val structure2 = objectOf(structure1) {
            items.forEach {
                it.city = "Khartoum"
            }
        }
        println(JSON.stringify(structure2))
        // {"items":[{"city":"Khartoum","name":"Bill"},{"city":"Khartoum","name":"Test2"}]}
    
        val structure3 = objectOf(structure0) {
            items.unsafeCast<Array<dynamic>>().forEach {
                it.name = "Shalaga44"
            }
        }
        println(JSON.stringify(structure3))
        //{"items":[{"city":"NY","name":"Shalaga44","orAnything":"Literly, anything!"},{"city":"Test","name":"Shalaga44"}]}
    
    }
```

Comment: Not from map, but seems to be usable. Thanks =)

Answer (score -2):

I may not truly understand your question so please excuse me if this doesn't help.
Personally, I'm a fan of using Klaxon:
https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon

You can write your own reflection utility to iterate over all of the properties in a data class and convert them to JSON.

Comment: Thanks, but its not that I need. 
I want to get pure javascript objects with structure like above, but without serialization/deserialization. 
An example of such a transformation, I pointed out in the post.